# Getting 2 different epoch values when running UnixData (ParseData) in perl

Tags: perl, timezone

```
use Date::Manip;

my $jobStartdate = "2024-3-20 15:46:00";
my $jobStartD = ParseDate("$jobStartdate");
my $jobStartEpoch = UnixDate($jobStartD,"%s");
```

When running the above code on 2 different machine, getting 2 different values of `$jobStartEpoch`. Why is it so? How can I correct the setting on the machines so that the values are same?

Comment: what's the different values? I mean, could you provide an example?

Comment: 1710941700 is jobStartEpoch - On one machine; 1710929100 is jobStartEpoch - On another machine

Answer (score 3):

The output depends on the time zone setting.

```
$ TZ=UTC ./script.pl
1710949560

$ TZ=Asia/Singapore ./script.pl
1710920760
```

I just added the following lines to the script:

```
use feature 'say';
say $jobStartEpoch;
```

Comment: how to check which timezone is set on the machine?

Comment: I checked via "date +%Z", and values are same i.e. IST

Comment: Is the clock correct on both the machines? What versions of `perl` and `Date::Manip` is installed on each?

Comment: @PPP, Re "*how to check which timezone is set on the machine?*", This shows the version of Date::Manip and the time zone used by Date::Manip: `perl -Mv5.14 -MDate::Manip=Date_TimeZone -e'say Date::Manip->VERSION; say Date_TimeZone()'`. (`date +%Z` isn't what you want.)